# Asymptotic Computation with Expectations

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, expectation

The question is, for any sequence of random variables $X_n$ with $\mathbb{E}[X_n^p]\rightarrow0$ for each $p\in \mathbb{N}$, can we prove (or find a counterexample to the claim that) $$ \frac{  \mathbb{E}[  X_n  ] \  \mathbb{E}[  X_n^3 ]^2 }{ Var( X_n )^3   }  \rightarrow 0 ? $$

I've tried a lot of combinations of the standard inequalities like Holder's, Jensen's, Markov's, and Chebyshev's to try and get an upper bound, but no luck so far for a general proof.

Also, working with the common probability distributions (e.g. Poisson, Normal, Exponential) there doesn't seem to be an obvious counter example.

I feel like the key might to be to show that $\frac{  \mathbb{E}[  X_n^3 ]^2 }{ Var( X_n )^3   }$ is bounded by some constant?

This is an extra-curricular question set by my lecturer - I'm happy to see full solutions or general hints towards the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following distribution for $X_n$:
$$
X_n = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}&\text{with probability} \frac{1}{n} \\
\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{n}}&\text{with probability} \frac{n-2}{n} \\
\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{n}}&\text{with probability} \frac{1}{n}
\end{cases}
$$
We have
$$
\mathsf{E}(X_n^p) \leq \left(\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{n}}\right)^p
$$
and therefore, when $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\mathsf{E}(X_n^p) \rightarrow 0$.

In addition, we have
$$
\mathsf{E}(X_n) = \frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{n}}, \quad \mathsf{E}(X_n^3) = \frac{8n + 12}{n^2} \quad\text{and}\quad \mathsf{Var}(X_n) = \frac{2}{n^{5/3}}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{\mathsf{E}(X_n)\mathsf{E}(X_n^3)^2}{\mathsf{Var}(X_n)^3}=\frac{\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{n}}\cdot \left(\frac{8n+12}{n^2}\right)^2}{\frac{8}{n^5}} \geq 16n^{8/3}
$$
and it is a counterexample.

Comment: Great stuff! That's a seriously non-trivial counter-example. How did you come up with that? :)

Comment: @ADB It is not very systematic. But I was trying to find a distribution with a very small variance but with large enough moments.